# How to add more than one value to a database table row?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have two tables named `event` and `activity`. I have `eventID` the foreign key of the `activity` table and `activityID` the FK of the `event` table. My problem is, an activity can have ONLY one event, but an event can have many activities. But I can only add one value to the `activityID` column in the `event` table. Can someone please suggest me a solution for it?

Comment: So remove the activityID on the event Table and have multiple rows in the activity table for the same event.  Each activity ties to one event and an event can have many activities.  However I think a more flexible design is to have Event, Activity, and EventActivities tables.  This allows an event to may many activities and an activity be linked to multiple events.  Basketball, Baseball, Football, Soccer, Swimming... activities.  Company Picnic, Music concert being events.  and the eventActivities would contain date/time info.

Answer (score 2):

You need a junction table . . . `EventActivities`, something like this:

```
create table EventActivities (
    EventActivitiesID int not null primary key auto_increment,
    eventId int not null references Events(EventId),
    activityId int not null references Activities(ActivityId)
);
```

Then your database will have three tables, and you probably don't need any column directly connecting `Activities` and `Events`.